# How to hide or change permissions on /api/ endpoint in Django Rest?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'd like to disable or set admin permissions on the /api/ endpoint - otherwise anybody can view our entire API. However, I don't want to remove the django rest UI entirely - I only want to stop people from being able to view the list of all the endpoints.

It seems like the two possible solutions are:

- Put in a redirect or somehow hide the endpoint
- Set admin-only permissions on the endpoint (and only that endpoint - so, only on /api/ - not on /api/things/)

I'm wondering if there's a "proper" way of going about this.

Answer (score 4):

**You can use [`permission classes`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions) to set admin user permission checks on `/api/` endpoint.**

Lets say, `MyView` is the view class for the `/api/` endpoint. We will set [`IsAdminUser`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser) permission class on this view. This will make our API to be accessible to only admin users.

**For Class-Based Views:**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import  IsAdminUser

class MyView(..):

    permisssion_classes = (IsAdminUser,) # set the permission class

    ..
```

**For Function-Based Views:**

```
@permission_classes((IsAdminUser, )) 
def my_view(..):
    ...
```

This will deny permission to any user having `user.is_staff` value as `False`, otherwise, permission will be allowed.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried, preferably, in a separate question with all the details.

Comment: Rahul Gupta, the ideia is to limit the API_Root list. If based on permisssions it should be something like: superuser gets json: {users, groups, files...} normaluser gets{files...}. Do you have an ideia on how to do this?

Comment: The current answer deals with only restricting API root i.e. `/api/` url to admin users. It will not limit the API root urls as you wanted. Sorry but currently i am not aware of a method to do that directly.

Comment: Even if you limit the urls in API root, you will have to add permission class on `users` and `groups` views also so as to limit access to admin users. Lets say, if you let the API root completely visible but add permission class on all the views, then if a normal user tries to access `users` API, DRF will not grant access to that user. So normal user will not be able to access the `users` and `groups` API but he can see those urls.

Comment: Yes, the need for permissions on classes is always required. The nice to have would be to restrict the endpoint list.

Comment: Agreed, its definitely better to hide those urls from normal users. Maybe you can start by looking into the DRF source code for `/api/` view and explore how the list of urls is generated.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this problem maybe not the most elegant, but it serves as an example.

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, base_name='users')
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet, base_name='groups')
router.register(r'tasks', views.TasksViewSet, base_name='tasks')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.APIRoot.as_view()),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class APIRoot(APIView):
    """
    API Root ...
    """
    def get(self, request):
        data = {
            "users": "http://localhost:5000/users/",
            "groups": "http://localhost:5000/groups/",
            "tasks": "http://localhost:5000/tasks/",
        }

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            data.pop("users")
            data.pop("groups")

        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `APIRootView` class, which defines the view for the root `/api/` endpoint, has an [undocumented private attribute](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/db37512a6e4fa5ba793b7e401d7014dfd0984995/rest_framework/routers.py#L297) `_ignore_model_permissions` which is set to `True`. This attribute is used to ensure that `DjangoModelPermissions` are [not applied to the root view](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/permissions.py#L219-L223), since the `DefaultRouter` root view has no `queryset` attribute, [which is necessary](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) for `DjangoModelPermissions` to work.

In short, if you set the `APIRootView` permissions to be something that is valid (e.g. `IsAuthenticated`) it is safe to set `_ignore_model_permissions` to `False`, which will cause the permission class to apply to the root view. As an example:

```py
class MyRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.APIRootView._ignore_model_permissions = False
        self.APIRootView.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that we are modifying `self.APIRootView` since `DefaultRouter` pulls `APIRootView` in [as an attribute](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/db37512a6e4fa5ba793b7e401d7014dfd0984995/rest_framework/routers.py#L332).

Beware that `_ignore_model_permissions` is a private, undocumented attribute and so there is no guarantee this will continue to work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's answer is technically correct, but there was something else I needed to do first.

I originally had:

```
router.register(r'things', things_viewsets.ThingViewSet)
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url((r'^api/'), include(router.urls)),
    ....
)
```

What I needed to do was:

```
router.register(r'api/things', things_viewsets.ThingViewSet) 
....

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Then I was able to simply remove /api/ and have it be a 404, or I could have added auth to it as Rahul explained.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SimpleRouter()` instead of `DefaultRouter()` in your `urls.py`.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter